# how to get sql AS value in Laravel?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

i am not much of a sql person. so help me.

```
$maxid = DB::select('select max(id) from product as mid');

return $maxid[0]->mid;
```

i want to get the max id from product table. but when run this i get an error

> Undefined property: stdClass::$mid

how to get max id as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alias is in the wrong place.  It should appear immediately after the column/function of column to which it corresponds, e.g. use this query:

```
$maxid = DB::select('select max(id) as mid from product');

return $maxid[0]->mid;
```